# Singleton not updating variable immediately

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, singleton

I have a singleton here is the header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Shared : NSObject
{
     NSString *messages;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *messages;

+ (Shared*)sharedInstance;

@end
```

Here is the implementation:

```
#import "Shared.h"
static Shared* sharedInstance;

@implementation Shared

@synthesize messages;


+ (Shared*)sharedInstance
{
    if ( !sharedInstance)
    {
        sharedInstance = [[Shared alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self )
    {
        messages = [[NSString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

The problem is when the I use

```
[Shared sharedInstance].messages = someVariable;
```

I can use 
    NSLog([Shared sharedInstance].messages);
and it shows the right output, but when i check from another class, NSLog doesn't show any output. I have the NSLog in the viewDidLoad method of another class, so when I click a button to go to the next view, it should output the value of the string, but it only works the second time. If the variable is set to dog, first it outputs nothing, then when I close the view and try again, it outputs dog. however, if I then change the variable to cat, it will output dog, and on the next attempt, output cat. I want it to update immediately, rather than remain one behind all the time.

EDIT: Here's the code from the other classes
This particular section is from a view controller class in the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Omitted, just preparing the DB, and emptying the array.
if ([db open])
    {
        FMResultSet *s = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT ShabadID FROM Shabad WHERE Gurmukhi LIKE %@", currentLine];
        while ([s next])
        {
            lineID = [s intForColumn:@"ShabadID"];
        }
        s = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT Gurmukhi, ShabadID FROM Shabad WHERE ShabadID LIKE %i", lineID];
        while ([s next])
        {

            //NSLog([s stringForColumn:@"Gurmukhi"]);
            [paragraphArray addObject:[s stringForColumn:@"Gurmukhi"]];
        }
        Text = @"";
        for (int i = 0; i<[paragraphArray count]; i++)
        {
            Text = [Text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", [paragraphArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        [Shared sharedInstance].messages = Text;
    }
```

Then in the another class, where I want the text to appear, in the viewDidLoad method,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog([Shared sharedInstance].messages);
    UITextView *myUITextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,30,310,450)];
    myUITextView.text = [Shared sharedInstance].messages;
    myUITextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    myUITextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    myUITextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GurbaniLipiLight" size:24];
    [myUITextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    myUITextView.editable = NO;
    myUITextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [ScrollerView addSubview:myUITextView];
}
```

Sure the NSLog doesn't show up right, but neither does the text in the textview, it does the same thing the NSLog does.

Comment: What does the code look like where it's showing the wrong thing?  If you move it to `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`, is it still wrong?

Comment: Can you include more of the "consuming" code? Specifically the code from the "other class", but ideally a full use case demonstrating the poor behavior.

Comment: singleton seems fine, could you please share the viewDidLoad and the second part of the code, when are you debug printing the value again? also, where is the second time? on button handler?

Comment: It's a better idea to use `NSLog(@"%@",[Shared sharedInstance].messages));`. Otherwise if your string contains anything `NSLog` would interpret as a formatting string you might run into problems.

Comment: @ctrahey Just edited the original post with it.

Comment: @MiroslavHudak Just added all relevant code to the original post. those are the only times I reference the singleton at all

Comment: @PhillipMills Nevermind, I'm stupid, that worked perfectly! Thank you, if you'd answer this question, I'd be more than happy to mark it as answered!

Comment: Should I assume that it was a case of which method the code was in?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, because it was in viewdidload, the view was loaded before any of the other code was executed. viewdidappear method, only invokes after the cell is tapped, if that makes any sense to you.

Comment: It makes perfect sense once I think about you using a segue, which I assume you are since `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` doesn't present a controller in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an assumption here about what order things happen in that's not quite right.  Assuming there's a segue involved in this, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called after the new view controller is prepared but before it's displayed.  Moving code to `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` delays execution until after the calling controller has set new data.

The other approach for communication between controllers that use a segue, is to use `prepareForSegue:` in the first controller to set data that the second controller needs.  That way it should be available when the view is loaded.